# Working with two applications in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, paperclip

I have rebuilt a project. I've migrated databases and now I need to transfer files. I can't just copy paste them. I need to reprocess them.

How can I load two Rails apps in console (or Rake Task) and work like that:

```
App1.attaches.all.each do |attach|
  new = App2.attach.new attach.attributes
  new.file = attach.file.url
  new.save
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd add a temporary model to the new application. If you have a model `Asset`, I'd add

```
class LegacyAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection (
        # connection credentials for old application
    )
end
```

Then you can use both models to convert the data and delete the `LegacyAsset` model after you're done.